# Drag and Drop SVG layers or groups

Tags: javascript, svg

I have been tasked with what could be the most difficult job of my career.  My employer wants me to build a custom sign generator tool that will use SVG files.

So a user will load the app/page and start off with an SVG file, then I need to be able to drag and drop each layer/group of the file to re-position it.  As well as change colors on a per group/layer basis.

I was able to change colors using Regular expressions and PHP but I am not sure how to do the drag and drop of each layer?

I can use JavaScript, HTML5, and PHP for any back-end processing.

I am really not sure where to begin though, could anyone with more knowledge in this area tell me a solid way to achieve this?

Also not that each Group/layer in the SVG file will not have an ID atrtribute set for them, so I cannot easily target a Group based on ID.

Comment: did you browse through the samples of svg based js libraries, like raphael?

Comment: I have looked at Raphael but haven't gotten to far with it as all the example show it creating an SVG file, where I am starting out with an existing SVG file that I need to let a user modify

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your life easier and just go with [SVG-edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html) which is already ready and built?

You can just remove all the unnecessary tools. You can simply configure it to have a pre-loaded SVG file and a pre-configured canvas size.

You can also change the pointer-events property to ''none'' of the pre-loaded elements so the user cannot move them or do anything with them.

As far as the drag and drop feature is re-configuring the ''IMPORT SVG'' function which is already there to import the selected drag-drop element on clicking it and loading it on the cursor for the user to set it down. Non-elegant but then again i am not sure i know how to code anything more than an S.O.S morse code:) beep beep beep, beep. just being immature.

Anyway all this assuming that you already have solid JS/SVG knowledge, it would be pretty straightforward in comparison to building an app from scratch.